# Linking from notmuch emails to org with date in the link description?

Tags: org-mode, email, notmuch

I am using org-mode to, well, organize information, and I often find it useful to link to email, where I use notmuch.  I can do C-c l in a notmuch buffer to store a link, and then C-c C-l in an org-mode buffer to insert it.

However, I would like to include the date from the email.  When I change

```
(setq org-link-email-description-format "%d %c: \"%.25s\"")
```

the documentation indicates that %d is supposed to include the date, but in the link text, it is always nil. What am I doing wrong here?

**To clarify:** this works as expected, except that the link text contains "nil" instead of the date.  Specifically, I am not trying to use it in the wrong buffer type.  (I don't understand what the replies are talking about)

Comment: You need to do `C-c l` *after* you change the value of `org-link-email-description`. I don't have `notmuch`, but  with `gnus` the stored link *does* contain the date. You should be able to use `edebug` to put a breakpoing on `org-notmuch-store-link` and verify that it is getting the date and storing it.

Comment: Apparently, you can only do `C-c  l` in two kinds of buffers: a buffer that shows a message (major mode `notmuch-show-mode`) or a tree-mode search buffer (major mode `notmuch-tree-mode`). Trying to save a link from a `notmuch-search` buffer e.g. will not work.

Answer (score 0):

`org-notmuch-store-link` checks that the major mode of the buffer where you do `C-c l` is one of (`notmuch-show-mode` `notmuch-tree-mode`). So if you have a buffer *showing* a message or a tree-search buffer initiated with `M-x notmuch-tree`, you should be able to get a link with a date. OTOH, if you are in a `notmuch-search` buffer (initiated with `M-x notmuch-search`, `C-c l` is a no-op.

After you save a link, check the value of `org-stored-links` to see whether it "took" - use `C-h v org-stored-links`.

I know very little (not even not much) about `notmuch`, so this is a stab in the dark. I hope it helps.